# bootstrap-datepicker date is not valid with datepicker.regional['fr'] on the second date while it's ok on the first

Tags: symfony, datepicker

In a symfony2 with bootstrap project I have a pair of date picker ( begin and end ). They work fine if I don't use :

```
jQuery(function ($) {
        $.datepicker.regional['fr'] = {
            closeText: 'Fermer',
            prevText: 'Précédent',
            nextText: 'Suivant',
            currentText: 'Aujourd\'hui',
            monthNames: ['janvier', 'février', 'mars', 'avril', 'mai', 'juin',
                'juillet', 'août', 'septembre', 'octobre', 'novembre', 'décembre'],
            monthNamesShort: ['janv.', 'févr.', 'mars', 'avril', 'mai', 'juin',
                'juil.', 'août', 'sept.', 'oct.', 'nov.', 'déc.'],
            dayNames: ['dimanche', 'lundi', 'mardi', 'mercredi', 'jeudi', 'vendredi', 'samedi'],
            dayNamesShort: ['dim.', 'lun.', 'mar.', 'mer.', 'jeu.', 'ven.', 'sam.'],
            dayNamesMin: ['D', 'L', 'M', 'M', 'J', 'V', 'S'],
            weekHeader: 'Sem.',
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
            firstDay: 1,
            isRTL: false,
            showMonthAfterYear: false,
            yearSuffix: ''};
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
    });
```

When I use the above code, the first date is ok while the second is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first initialize your datepicker with the right configs. Don't forget the jquerys links. I suggest you as follow:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(){
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        closeText: 'Fermer',
        prevText: 'Précédent',
        nextText: 'Suivant',
        currentText: 'Aujourd\'hui',
        monthNames: ['janvier', 'février', 'mars', 'avril', 'mai', 'juin',
            'juillet', 'août', 'septembre', 'octobre', 'novembre', 'décembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['janv.', 'févr.', 'mars', 'avril', 'mai', 'juin',
            'juil.', 'août', 'sept.', 'oct.', 'nov.', 'déc.'],
        dayNames: ['dimanche', 'lundi', 'mardi', 'mercredi', 'jeudi', 'vendredi', 'samedi'],
        dayNamesShort: ['dim.', 'lun.', 'mar.', 'mer.', 'jeu.', 'ven.', 'sam.'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D', 'L', 'M', 'M', 'J', 'V', 'S'],
        weekHeader: 'Sem.',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''
        });$.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] ); // texte en french marche pas
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was a symfony related trouble.

I code this in my formtype

```
...
->add('createdAt1', TextType::class, array(
                'attr' => ['class' => 'js-datepicker'],
                'required' => false,
                    )
            )
...
```

instead of :

```
...
->add('createdAt1', 'datetime', array(
       'widget' => 'single_text',
        'input' => 'string',
         'html5' => false,
          'attr' => ['class' => 'js-datepicker'],
           'required' => false,
                )
        )
```

and manage the date with a strtotime in my repo.